# Core Location - Zoom in on current position

Tags: iphone, core-location

Is there anyway using Core Location to zoom in on the users current location, when my map loads its showing the entire world, I want the map to zoom in about 3km above the users current location.

Regards,
Stephen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, see thread:

[iPhone Mapkit Blue Dot / User Location Region Zoom Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2412899/iphone-mapkit-blue-dot-user-location-region-zoom-question)